# multiple union all in common table expression

Tags: sql, recursive-query

i am just playing with cte to print 1 to 10 or printing 12 months

```
create table eventlist 
  (
    id int identity(1,1) not null, 
    edate smalldatetime 
  )
  select * from eventlist

  insert into eventlist select '01/01/2012'




  ;with cte AS
    (
       select edate from eventlist 
       union all 

       select dateadd(M,1,edate) from cte where MONTH(edate)<12


    )

    select MONTH(edate), YEAR (edate) from cte
```

but suddenly i just combine the another union all seciton in cte like this

```
;with cte AS
    (
       select edate from eventlist 
       union all 

       select dateadd(M,1,edate) from cte where MONTH(edate)<12
       union all 
       select dateadd(Y,1,edate) from cte where YEAR(edate)<2013

    )

    select MONTH(edate), YEAR (edate) from cte
```

when i just run this i will get this error

**The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.**

i understand this error due to limit of recurssion  but 
**`i just want to understand how will this recurssion will work ?`**

Comment: Remember you can change recursion limit (WITH MAXRECURSION = 365 ) and let me know do the first: 'to understand recursion first you need to understand recursion'.

Comment: Do you want the first days of all months of 2012 and 2013 or ALL dates of 2012 and 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` is the abbreviation for DateOfYear, not for year. Try `yy` or `yyyy` or even better the `year`.

The error you get is because you exceed the recusrion limit. You are asking the CTE to start from a date (`'2012-01-01'`) and in every (recursion) step, produce the day after a month (`'2012-01-01'` for the first step) **and** the next day (`'2012-01-02'` for the first step). Then in the second step, 4 more rows will have to be produced, 2 for each new row produced in the 1st step. Then 8, then 16, etc. (The condition `MONTH(edate)<12` will be effective only after you have produced 2^10 new rows in the 11th step. Even then, it will only slightly limit the number of the rows produced in the next steps. Your original query if there was no recursion limit would create millions of rows).

That's why your CTE will return not 24 rows as you expect, but 90 instead (even when you change `Y` to `Year`),  because of the double recursion.

Use this:

```
; with cte AS
(
   select edate from eventlist 
   union all 
   select dateadd(Month,1,edate) from cte where MONTH(edate)<12
)

, cte2 AS
(
   select edate from cte 
   union all 
   select dateadd(Year,1,edate) from cte2 where YEAR(edate)<2013
)

select MONTH(edate), YEAR(edate) from cte2 ;
```

or this one which is I think simpler:

```
; with cte AS
(
   select edate from eventlist 
   union all 
   select dateadd(Month,1,edate) from cte where edate < '2013-12-01'
)

select MONTH(edate), YEAR(edate) from cte ;
```